Besides Cantonese, in which language is the default way to tell time to use the number shown by the minute hand (not the minute) on the clock?
What's the time?
There are many intricate ways to tell time in different languages: (eg. German: 4:40 = ten after half five, Thai: different names for hours in the evening/morning).
In Cantonese, the system is very straightforward: You read whatever it's shown on the clock and there is no need to convert anything. The default informal way to tell time is to read the numbers the minute hand (not the minutes)point at on the clock:
5:15 - five o'clock three
5:19 - five o'clock four
5:17 - five o'clock three/ four/ a bit more than three/ gonna be four soon
When someone just wants to know the number shown by the minute hand, he would ask "on how many?" 搭幾
5:15 - on three 搭三
It is an approximation. In case someone needs to know the exact minute, he would ask "What's the minute now" instead of "What's the time"
Nowadays, clocks on mobile phones are digital, it's also very common to read the minutes:
5:03 - five o'clock zero-three (minute)
17:10 - five o'clock ten minute/ or read the numbers: one seven one zero
5:19 - five o'clock nineteen (minute)
"Minutes" less than thirteen generally would not be dropped or it would mean the numbers pointed at by the minute hand.
Which language has a similar system of reading the numbers on the minute hand? Most languages tell the minutes instead.

In some regions of Germany, 4:40 is actually 5 before three-quarter 5. And 4:15 is quarter 5 (one is dropped).

I don't know any examples, but it wouldn't surprise me if this wasn't uncommon amongst cultures which did not previously use hours & minutes before the introduction of European-style clocks

I suggest this is about Linguistics but rather, about the Cantonese and English languages. If anyone thinks SE Linguistics insists translations between given language pair do fall within the scope of the site, I apologise.
Either way, I hope you can find a collaborating translator because as they stand, the given examples don't work in English.
